# Existence of special solution

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and $b$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R^n}$. Prove that if the system of $n$ equations in $m$ unknowns
$$xA = b$$
does not have a solution then the system of equations 
$$Ay = 0$$ and $$by = 1$$ 
has a solution

My attempt: If $xA = b$ does not have a solution then it means that the row space of $A$ does not contain $b$ i.e. the vectors in the rows of $A$ and the vector $b$ taken together are independent, but I dont see how this means that $Ay = 0$ and $by = 1$ has a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the contrapositive, assume that there exists a $y$ with $by=0$ and $Ay = 0$. We want to prove that $b$ is in the row space. This is immediate from the fact that the row space is perpendicular to the null space of $A$. Since $y$ is in the null space and perpendicular to $b$, $b$ must be in the row space.